# What is "At Styles" in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Hercule Poirot (1989-present) 
This fussy Belgian sleuth first appeared in Agatha Christie’s novel The Mysterious Affair At Styles in 1920.

Question: Is "at styles" translated like "at styles of films in that period of time" or "At Styles" is a place or name of a city or town?

Answer (score 3):

According to the description of the book provided by Amazon it's a place.

> The story opens in England during the First World War at **Styles** Court,
>   an Essex country manor

Comment: Just like saying "The mysterious affair **at home**"... Home being where the heart is...